# Why would autoconf/automake project link against installed library instead of local development library?

Tags: msbuild, build, autoconf, automake, libtool

I'm creating a library `libgdata` that has some tests and non-installed programs. I am running into the problem that once I've installed the library once, the programs seem to be linking to the installed version and not the local version in `../src/libgdata.la` any longer.

What could cause this? Am I doing something horribly wrong?

Here is what my `test/Makefile.am` looks like:

```
INCLUDES = -I$(top_srcdir)/src/ -I$(top_srcdir)/test/

# libapiutil contains all of our dependencies!
AM_CXXFLAGS = $(APIUTIL_CFLAGS)
AM_LDFLAGS = $(APIUTIL_LIBS)

LDADD = $(top_builddir)/src/libgdata.la

noinst_PROGRAMS = gdatacalendar gdatayoutube

gdatacalendar_SOURCES = gdatacalendar.cc

gdatayoutube_SOURCES = gdatayoutube.cc

TESTS = check_bare

check_PROGRAMS = $(TESTS)

check_bare_SOURCES = check_bare.cc
```

(`libapiutil` is another library that has some helper stuff for dealing with libcurl and libxml++)

So, for instance, if I run the tests without having installed anything, everything works fine. I can make changes locally and they are picked up by these programs right away.

If I install the package, these programs will compile (it seems like it does actually look locally for the headers), but once I run the program it complains about missing symbols.

As far as I can tell, it is linking against the newly built library (../src/libgdata.la) based on the make output, so I'm not sure why this would be happening. If i remove the installed files, the local changes to src/* are picked up just fine.

I've included the make output for gdatacalendar below.

```
g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -I../src/ -I../test/   -I/home/altern8/workspaces/4355/dev-install/include -I/usr/include/libxml++-2.6 -I/usr/lib/libxml++-2.6/include -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/usr/include/glibmm-2.4 -I/usr/lib/glibmm-2.4/include -I/usr/include/sigc++-2.0 -I/usr/lib/sigc++-2.0/include -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include   -g -O2 -MT gdatacalendar.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/gdatacalendar.Tpo -c -o gdatacalendar.o gdatacalendar.cc
mv -f .deps/gdatacalendar.Tpo .deps/gdatacalendar.Po
/bin/bash ../libtool --tag=CXX   --mode=link g++ -I/home/altern8/workspaces/4355/dev-install/include -I/usr/include/libxml++-2.6 -I/usr/lib/libxml++-2.6/include -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/usr/include/glibmm-2.4 -I/usr/lib/glibmm-2.4/include -I/usr/include/sigc++-2.0 -I/usr/lib/sigc++-2.0/include -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include   -g -O2 -L/home/altern8/workspaces/4355/dev-install/lib -lapiutil -lcurl -lgssapi_krb5 -lxml++-2.6 -lxml2 -lglibmm-2.4 -lgobject-2.0 -lsigc-2.0 -lglib-2.0    -o gdatacalendar gdatacalendar.o ../src/libgdata.la 
mkdir .libs
g++ -I/home/altern8/workspaces/4355/dev-install/include -I/usr/include/libxml++-2.6 -I/usr/lib/libxml++-2.6/include -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/usr/include/glibmm-2.4 -I/usr/lib/glibmm-2.4/include -I/usr/include/sigc++-2.0 -I/usr/lib/sigc++-2.0/include -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include -g -O2 -o .libs/gdatacalendar gdatacalendar.o  -L/home/altern8/workspaces/4355/dev-install/lib /home/altern8/workspaces/4355/dev-install/lib/libapiutil.so /usr/lib/libcurl.so -lgssapi_krb5 /usr/lib/libxml++-2.6.so /usr/lib/libxml2.so /usr/lib/libglibmm-2.4.so /usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.so /usr/lib/libsigc-2.0.so /usr/lib/libglib-2.0.so ../src/.libs/libgdata.so  -Wl,--rpath -Wl,/home/altern8/workspaces/4355/dev-install/lib
creating gdatacalendar
```

Help. :)

**UPDATE**

I get the following messages when I try to run the calendar program when I've added the `addCommonRequestHeader()` method to the Service class after I had installed the library without the `addCommonRequestHeader()` method.

```
/home/altern8/workspaces/4355/libgdata/test/.libs/lt-gdatacalendar:
symbol lookup error:
/home/altern8/workspaces/4355/libgdata/test/.libs/lt-gdatacalendar:
undefined symbol:
_ZN55gdata7service7Service22addCommonRequestHeaderERKSsS4_
```

Eugene's suggestion to try setting the `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable did not help.

**UPDATE 2**

I did two tests. First, I did this after blowing away my dev-install directory (--prefix) and in that case, it creates `test/.libs/lt-gdatacalendar`. Once I have installed the library, though, it creates `test/.libs/gdatacalendar` instead. The output of ldd is the same for both with one exception:

```
# before install
# ldd test/.libs/lt-gdatacalendar
libgdata.so.0 => /home/altern8/workspaces/4355/libgdata/src/.libs/libgdata.so.0 (0xb7c32000)

# after install
# ldd test/.libs/gdatacalendar
libgdata.so.0 => /home/altern8/workspaces/4355/dev-install/lib/libgdata.so.0 (0xb7c87000)
```

What would cause this to create lt-gdatacalendar in one case but gdatacalendar in another?

The output of ldd on libgdata is:

```
altern8@goldfrapp:~/workspaces/4355/libgdata$ ldd /home/altern8/workspaces/4355/libgdata/src/.libs/libgdata.so.0
        linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xb7f7c000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xb7f3b000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6 (0xb7dec000)
        /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xb7f7d000)
```

Comment: Could you also post output of ldd lt-gdatacalendar

Comment: And then output of ldd on all your libs

Comment: Hm, what is this lt- prefix indeed?

Comment: Same problem here. I'm building my project which depends on a library. This library is provided by my system (installed with pkg under /usr/local). I have installed a newer version of the library with a different ABI in my homedir. I've set my LD_LIBRARY_PATH, PKG_CONFIG_PATH, etc but in the libtool is run with -L/usr/local before -L/home/me/local/lib and fails because of missing symbols.

Answer (score 2):

I think I've sorted this out.

The problem should be that libtool sees the "-L" flag in the command line before it sees the "../src/libgdata.so" part. In this case, it executes the linker with "-Wl,-rpath,..." for that "-L" path. If that path contains "libgdata.so", then it will always be used, which is the case here.

In my case, I've rearranged "prog_LDADD" to like like this:
"prog_LDADD = $(top_builddir)/src/my_lib.so $(DEPENDENCY_LIBS)"

In your case, try to delete AM_LDFLAGS and write:

LDADD = $(top_builddir)/src/libgdata.la $(APIUTIL_LIBS)

Comment: I'll have to give that a try when I get back to this project. My workaround (which was *very* dirty) involved linking to the static library: LDADD = $(top_builddir)/src/.libs/libgdata.a It was acceptable only because this was for the test directory.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how to do that in autoconf, but final command might need to have -L../src, so linker can find newly built library first.

Try manually running last command with that addition and see if that helps.

EDIT: Ok, I guess misread it, thought it wasn't linking, but you are saying it links but doesn't run?

If that is the case, run ldd on your binary and see which .so it picks up -- most likely  installed (and outdated) ones.

In this case, either install updated libs before running, or export LD_LIBRARY_PATH env variable before running.

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/path to freshly built libs"
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but this did not seem to help any.

Answer (score 1):

I know that for dependencies to work correctly, you need to refer to `libgdata.la` with a relative path in `LDADD`; it's possible that affects the situation you're describing as well.

I'm not sure why, though. The behavior you're describing does seem a bit odd; and perhaps worth reporting to the libtool developers.

Answer (score 0):

Without -no-install libtool creates script wrappers and puts the executables into the .libs/ subdir (linked with the *installed* libraries). Calling the wrapper makes your executable load/link with your local (not installed) library - so everything works fine, e.g. `make check` does not test the installed but your freshly baken library.

In some cases (e.g. when debugging or valgrinding), you do not want to have those wrappers, but real executables directly linked with your local library. For this you use `AM_LDFLAGS = -no-install` (or just set it for single targets).

More details [here](https://autotools.io/libtool/wrappers.html)